# Error during ubuntu installation : warning source ID XXXXX was not found when attemping to remove it

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, 20.04

When trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04, I face an error during installation process:

```
warning source ID XXXXX not found when attemping to remove it
```

- installation source: live USB 4GB
- destination: usb 64GB
- laptop: acer aspire V5-122P

I tried several solutions like:

1. make disk image using Rofus or unetbootin =>  same error
2. running check sum on installation package: all ok no error
3. try different version like 20.04 or even 16.04: == same error
   4) use gparted to partition disk before installation: => same result

I'm made several trials since last Feb 2020 but all lead to same result.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be just a warning , not a fatal error which prevents the system installation .Those are just for the ubiquity's ( ubuntu installer ) frontend .  I think the problem is somewhere else. You can check the log files in "/var/log/installer" and search for the "error" to see what's wrong with the installer.

Comment: You mean to run installation again ?? .. if so .. how can I stop installation to check this file ?? Once installation started , it cannot be stopped .. kindly explain more.

Comment: No , I mean the problem should be somewhere else. The information in your post indicates just some warnings , not errors that prevent your installation. Look what is printed as "error" in the logs beneath the slideshow. If you find the error message (not warning ) then we can investigate what was wrong with it. If you run the installation again and again , the problem might persist. So there should be an error message about something.